# Unable to send http post request from Microsoft Teams messagecard's potention action button

Tags: http-post, webhooks, microsoft-teams

I'm sending a card to a Microsoft Teams channel with a button that contains a post request. 
When I click the button I got the following error :

"Failed to send

Could not complete the requested action. Please try again later."

```
@type": "MessageCard",
"@context": "https://schema.org/extensions",
"summary": "{SUMMÁRIA}",
"themeColor": "0078D7",
"title": "{TÁJ} - {TÓÉ} ",
"sections": [
    ...sectionDescription],
"potentialAction": [
    {
    "name": "BUTTON LABEL",
    "target": "https://<targetURL>",
    /* I also tried this one "headers": [{
    "name": "Authorization",
    "value": "Basic base64",
    }, {"name" : "Content-Type", "value": "application/json"}],*/
    "headers": [{"Authorization": "Basic <BASE64STUFF>"}, {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, ],
    "@type": "HttpPOST",
    "url": "https://<TARGETURL>",
    "bodyContentType": "application/json",
    "body": JSON.stringify({
        "buildType": {
            "id": "hereisTheid"
        },
        "comment": {
            "text": "message"
        },
        "properties": {
            "property": [{
                    "name": "proprety",
                    "value": "valueofproperty"
                },
                {
                    "name": "properyt",
                    "value": "valueofProperty"
                }
            ]
        },
    }),
    },
    {
        "@type": "HttpPOST",
        "name": "View Build",
        "target": "https://....."
    },
    {
        "@type": "HttpPOST",
        "name": "Test results",
        "target": "http://..."
    }
]
```

How can I identify the button's response?

Comment: Are you trying this in a free account? If not, could you please confirm that the account in which you created the connector and the account where you are testing this post action is the same?

Comment: @abu - Are you still facing this issue? Are you using [Incoming Webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook#add-an-incoming-webhook-to-a-teams-channel) or [created new Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-creating)?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT Yes I'm, I'm posting the card from a webhook that contains the HTTP post as described above

Answer (score 2):

Try using Teams in the web client instead of the desktop client. It might give a better view on this because you have access to the browser F12 Developer tools.

Comment: Some extra "info" : "errorCode":"HttpRequestException"}}